# Animation error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, animation, cocos2d-iphone

Can anyone help me with this error message I get when I try to play a game level in a game I am developing.

What happens is  that on starting the game the game starts and runs fine but after the player wins or loses the game and wishes to replay or play the game level again from the main menu, the following error comes up(Please see the screen shot below):

[image: Screenshot]

I suspect my animations but I really cannot place what and where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

animations_ has probably already been released, if you did not retain it, then you do not have to release it.

Comment: Thanks man for your help and *me to the right direction. I was releasing my animations twice. Cheers!